# Flutter: iOS Emulator for Windows

Tags: android, android-emulator, dart, flutter

I have started to learn **flutter** by Google and installed it in **android studio**. I have an emulator for Android but I don't know how to run this in iOS.

Is it possible to run an iOS emulator in windows? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: using VMWare  u can install Xcode and then u can use IOS simulate for running any application in IOS

Comment: any other way that consume lot of ram and process

Comment: see my below answer hope it's helpful for u

Comment: any way for ubuntu ?

Comment: **This only will help you to show how the UI works on iOS.** [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0E8Z.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0E8Z.jpg) **try this then run**

Comment: I agree, it would be super useful if Microsoft would allow the Xamarin Simulators to work for flutter.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If the purpose is only testing how the UI works on iOS, then Flutter Inspector will do the job.

Click on the Flutter Inspector from the right pane and click on 'Toggle Platform Mode' from the top menu of the newly opened box. This will change the UI of the running app on your device.

Comment: @Michael Hathi I can't find the flutter inspector :(

Comment: @Shayan make sure you have installed the flutter plugin for Android Studio. Once installed, flutter inspector can be found in the right side pane.

Comment: This doesn't do the job. There are unexpected differences between flutter on android and ios that aren't shown by changing anything in the flutter inspector.

Comment: @Shayan I used Android 4.1. I can't find Toggle Platform Mode in Flutter Inspector.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 14):

Most iOS developers use (in a separate window) VMWare WorkStation (a virtual Machine) and install MacOS with XCode.

You can always go back to VMWare, but these 2 links might be helpful.

https://www.dreamytricks.net/ios-emulator-windows-run-ios-apps/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Comment: i think i need to install VMWare another  emulator is not quite smooth ..thanks @Mohammad Ali

Comment: Most developers will just buy a mac. It can build for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 7):

maybe it's too late. But I will answer anyway. You can try IOS UI using this flutter package [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview).

Comment: No, it is not showing platform specific widgets, it is just changing device size.

Comment: Thank you! Settings this up took a bit but now it is working amazing-- this allows me to debug on my laptop with any popular device out there! Great recommendation

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is no direct way to run the app on iOS emulator unless you use Mac pc or laptop. However, this article provides you with an indirect way to run the app. [Developing and debugging Flutter apps for iOS without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI), it's a tool that will let you access a remote Mac OS build machine on which you can test your app.

Odevio is a desktop application that can be installed from the website: https://www.odevio.com

Once installed you can setup your Apple Developer Account with Odevio in the Apple menu.

You can also directly start building within the build menu and with a Configuration build type.

For a more detailed tutorial you can check a full tutorial here : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/5_create_apple_developer_account.html