# How to have iPhone emulator on Windows using Flutter?

Tags: iphone, flutter, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I am new to **Flutter**. I want to test my app on an **iPhone** emulator (or simulator) just to see how does it look in real time?

I am using these:

1. Windows 10
2. Visual Studio Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: iOS Emulator for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002527/11067496)

Comment: You can't, impossible with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You need macOS to install Xcode, without which iOS development & running is not possible.

With windows, you cannot even run it on an iPhone if you had one.

Comment: What about Flutter Inspector? One suggested me this, but not familiar that much with it. 
 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector