# How to add More Devices to Flutter in VSC

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, select, device

This is what is showing in his Project:
Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZmsG.jpg

This is what is showing in my Project:
Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5aQh.jpg

Comment: All the devices you create with emulators will probably look like the tabs in the photo. Or if the USB debugging mode of the device you connected with the cable is turned on, it will still see it.[Android Studio Create and manage virtual devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Comment: How can i make it show the "Start IOS Simulator" in the First Image?

Comment: Nope, if i download one will it work?

Comment: Are you using a Windows computer?

Comment: yes I'm on windows

Comment: You can look at this:
[Flutter: iOS Emulator for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002527/flutter-ios-emulator-for-windows).
But you should know that it is very challenging :)

Comment: I haven't even start coding in flutter yet, just setting it up took me a while :( , even though, I will check the link, thanks for the help!

Comment: You do know that you will need access to a Mac in order to publish an app on the app store, don't you? It is probably better to build and test the android stuff on windows, and then use the Mac and it's emulator for the iOS testing.

Answer (score 0):

Any device (Android/Ios) connected to computer in debug mode will automatically show up on visual studio. For emulators, it is sufficient to have downloaded and opened Xcode(IOS) and Android Studio(Android) and to have run the devices directly from the respective apps to then automatically display them also on visual studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).